# Preserve trailing whitespace in html template of angular component?

Tags: html, angular

I want to display a comma separated list of names like `test1, test2, test3`. I am using something like below:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" *ngFor="let object of objectList; let i = index;">
        {{object.name}}{{((i+1) === objectList.length) ? '' : ', '}}
 </div>
```

All the trailing whitespaces are removed and result is `test1,test2,test3`. I was using `&nbsp` but I read at some places that it was not recommended to use.
How should I preserve these whitespaces?

edit: code didn't have that style tag earlier (which is in a separate .css file in the actual code but placing it inline for the sake of the question)

Comment: What happens if you use `ng-container` instead of `div`? The problem might be that for each item of the array, a `div` element is created, and therefore the white space is lost.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest two changes.

1. At the moment, each element of the array is rendered in it's own `<div>` tag. So it'd look like following

```html
<div>test1, </div>
<div>test2, </div>
<div>test3, </div>
<div>test4, </div>
<div>test5</div>
```

Whereas you might need to enclose all the elements in a single `<div>` container like

```html
<div>test1, test2, test3, test4, test5</div>
```

For that you could iterate the array in a `<ng-container>` tag. It'll be commented out in the final DOM and would render additional elements.

2. You could use the `last` [local variable](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) of the `*ngFor` directive instead of checking using the index and the array's length.

Try the following

```html
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let object of objectList; let last = last;">
    {{ object.name }}{{ last ? '' : ', ' }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you are right about those extra `divs` created but the trailing whitepaces getting removed, so there is no space after the commas. Is it because of `style='dispaly: inline-block`?
I will try your solution with `ng-container`